# System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit == 24 --> BUG?

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-4.0

When checking the System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit in .Net 4 in my debugger, I see really high numbers.  I see 24 on one machine and see 48 on another machine.

This is even the case for a newly created ASP.NET MVC 3 project without any configuration changes done to it.  Is this a bug?  The documentation clearly states that the default is 2:

> The maximum number of concurrent connections allowed by a ServicePoint
>   object. **The default value is 2.**
>
> From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit(v=VS.100).aspx

The DefaultNonPersistentConnectionLimit and DefaultPersistentConnectionLimit fields are more realistic 4 and 2, respectively, but the DefaultConnectionLimit number seems out of range.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not a bug. It's propably 12 per CPU.

The value comes from [`<connectionManagement>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb6y0fyc%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) in your Web.config or Machine.config. If neither of files contains  element it's probably configured by `autoConfig=True` setting at [`<processModel>` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w2sway1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: If you were to decompile the v4.0 System.Web and look at the 'SetAutoConfigLimits' method, you'll see this set to 2 * # of CPUs.  In .NET 4.5 this appears to have been changed and the value is now set to Int32.MaxValue (0x7fffffff).

Comment: That should've been 12 * # of CPUs.

Comment: Kevin is totally right, with framework 4.5 it is indeed Int32.MaxValue. It' in the System.Web.HttpRuntime class.

Comment: For web projects it's set to Int32.MaxValue.   But in an Azure WorkerRole(and I haven't checked, but I suspect a console or desktop app too) it's set to 2 by default.   Probably because the HttpRuntime isn't being invoked.