# What to set ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit to

Tags: azure

ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit sets the maximum number of concurrent sessions for a Worker Role, but how can I find the best value here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the best advise on getting the value is here on [forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com:80/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredata/thread/d84ba34b-b0e0-4961-a167-bbe7618beb83). Also read the knowledge base article listed.

The point is that the default of 2 will get you into trouble with connection drops.

Answer (score 12):

According to [Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821268), 12 * [Number of logical CPUs] is a good value.

If you're using .Net 4.5, the defaults [are already set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5649013/1727) to more sensible values.

Comment: I'm not sure if that last line is correct - I checked the default in my application, which is built specifically using .Net 4.5, and it still defaults to 2. Someone else might want to verify and alter the answer (if they find the same case, or make the comment more specific as it might be more than simply .Net 4.5 - MSDN does state:  "When used in the server environment (ASP.NET) DefaultConnectionLimit defaults to higher number of connections, which is 10.", at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I can confirm that on my Web API Azure website (.NET 4.5) `DefaultConnectionLimit` is set to 2. The linked answer suggests that the "sensible defaults" are set by "classic" ASP.NET (System.Web) whereas in other hosting environments, for example Web API in my case, thing may be different.

Comment: Note that in ASP.NET 4.5 it is now `int.MaxValue`

Comment: @OhadSchneider, any msdn links for this?

Comment: @MahdiK. I think I just looked at it in ILSpy

Comment: @OhadSchneider: I guess the value is still 2, and this happens when you self host the app. However hosting on a web server, you read the value from machine-level configs which makes it 12 connection per logical CPUs. Reference: for asp.net apps the default connection limit is managed at machine level configs in processModel/autoConfig:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/administration/7w2sway1(v=vs.85). Please note that at the below link the value seems to be 2 which is not the current default value which is 12.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/kb/821268