# Cloud service worker role ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit

Tags: azure-cloud-services

While reading through the code, often the code sample has a line 'ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit=12', trying to understand what this is, all seems to point to outbound connection limit for Http request. If my worker role does not make any request to other resources, shall I even care about this setting? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if your Role does not make any request to other resources, then this setting does not matter to you.

You can learn more about this setting at the following link.
  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2009/05/20/understanding-maxservicepointidletime-and-defaultconnectionlimit.aspx

[What to set ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760403/what-to-set-servicepointmanager-defaultconnectionlimit-to)

-Nithin