# ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit in .net core?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx, coreclr

I am porting a web api 2 service to .net core and I found this line in my old web api service.

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = int.MaxValue;
```

This line of code increases the connection limit. I don't know if it's for the computer or the framework or just the application. And after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24010375/1365053) answer on stackoverflow, I also realise that setting it to int.max may not be the best idea. However I would still like to have control over it in my new .net core service.

How do I modify/increase DefaultConnectionLimit in .net core. Also, How do I even know what's the default limit in .net core ? (if that's a valid question :) )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In ASP.NET 5 apps, use `WinHttpHandler.MaxConnectionsPerServer`. Its default value is `int.MaxValue`.

For details, see the [.NET Portability Analyzer from the Visual Studio Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1177943e-cfb7-4822-a8a6-e56c7905292b) and [`WinHttpHandler.MaxConnectionsPerServer` on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.winhttphandler.maxconnectionsperserver%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

[image: What to do in ASP.NET 5 apps...]