# ServicePointManager in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm trying to convert an existing class library code to a .NET Core class library. In that code in a `static` constructor I have the following:

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

I did some searching and `ServicePointManager` is no longer available in .NET Core, and `WinHttpHandler` should be used now ([ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit in .net core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36398474/servicepointmanager-defaultconnectionlimit-in-net-core)).

My question is what exactly is the `ServicePointManager` and what are those properties that are being set?

The `WinHttpHandler` is not `static` as `ServicePointManager` so I'd have to create an instance to set those properties? do I need to change all my http calls to make use of that instance?

Comment: Were you able to port pushsharp over? I'm in the process of doing it and assume this is what you are doing.

Answer (score 12):

`WinHttpHandler` inherits from `HttpMessageHandler`, so you can pass it as a parameter when constructing you `HttpClient` like follows:

```
WinHttpHandler httpHandler = new WinHttpHandler();
httpHandler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpHandler);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

ServicePointManager is available in .NET Core from v2.0

> Assembly System.Net.ServicePoint, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51

That said, I have implemented my HTTP Client calls using:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler handler;  // use DI etc to create 
if (options.SkipSsl)  // config driven
    handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (req, cer, ch, err) => true;
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44540071/4292717

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following namespaces:

```
using System.Net.Http;

using System.Net.Http.Headers;
```

then change your line as below,

```
WinHttpHandler httpHandler = new 
WinHttpHandler();

httpHandler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls;
```

instead of

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | 
SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

Happy Coding !!!