# Testing async methods in Visual Studio 2017 with .net 4.5+ appear to block on two threads. Running the same code in .net core 2.0 does not block

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, restsharp

I had a relatively painful head-pounding issue the last few days.

While executing unit tests intended to verify async behavior in Visual Studio 2017, the async method calls appear to be blocked, but ONLY when I made calls to a web API (I promise, I had locally mocked services first, but then needed some integration tests with an API to prove the web requests behaved similarly).

I finally rang a friend to help me think this through, to which he re-wrote the same tests and showed his tests behaved as expected. The only differentiating factor was that he wrote his tests in VS2017 with .net Core 2.0.

Example Code:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestRestSharpExecuteTaskAsync()
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(async s =>
        {
            // Using RestSharp, but also tested using raw WebRequests
            var restClient = new RestClient("http://google.com");
            var request = new RestRequest("/", RestSharp.Method.GET);

            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff")));
            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            var response = await restClient.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in {1} milliseconds", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff"), stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
        })).Wait();
    }
```

What is currently confusing me, is that when this code is executed in VS2017 with .net 4.5+ (also tested 4.6.2), the results show that there are clearly tasks waiting:

```
11/30/2017 10:45:45.214 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
11/30/2017 10:45:45.253 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
11/30/2017 10:45:45.253 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
11/30/2017 10:45:45.253 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
11/30/2017 10:45:45.253 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
11/30/2017 10:45:45.254 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
11/30/2017 10:45:45.254 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
11/30/2017 10:45:45.254 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
11/30/2017 10:45:45.254 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
11/30/2017 10:45:45.254 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
11/30/2017 10:45:45.368 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 151 milliseconds
11/30/2017 10:45:45.368 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 115 milliseconds
11/30/2017 10:45:45.414 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 161 milliseconds
11/30/2017 10:45:45.420 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 166 milliseconds
11/30/2017 10:45:45.466 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 212 milliseconds
11/30/2017 10:45:45.473 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 218 milliseconds
11/30/2017 10:45:45.520 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 266 milliseconds
11/30/2017 10:45:45.522 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 268 milliseconds
11/30/2017 10:45:45.570 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 315 milliseconds
11/30/2017 10:45:45.578 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 323 milliseconds
```

However, when run in the same VS2017 IDE with a .net Core 2.0 project, the tasks execute asynchronously as expected:

```
11/30/2017 10:45:11.922 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
11/30/2017 10:45:11.976 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
11/30/2017 10:45:11.976 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
11/30/2017 10:45:11.977 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
11/30/2017 10:45:11.977 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
11/30/2017 10:45:11.977 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
11/30/2017 10:45:11.977 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
11/30/2017 10:45:11.977 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
11/30/2017 10:45:11.977 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
11/30/2017 10:45:11.977 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
11/30/2017 10:45:12.153 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 230 milliseconds
11/30/2017 10:45:12.153 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 176 milliseconds
11/30/2017 10:45:12.153 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 175 milliseconds
11/30/2017 10:45:12.153 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 175 milliseconds
11/30/2017 10:45:12.153 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 175 milliseconds
11/30/2017 10:45:12.153 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 176 milliseconds
11/30/2017 10:45:12.153 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 176 milliseconds
11/30/2017 10:45:12.153 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 175 milliseconds
11/30/2017 10:45:12.153 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 176 milliseconds
11/30/2017 10:45:12.154 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 177 milliseconds
```

Is this an IDE configuration? A bug in .net 4.x? What gives?

EDIT: The issue becomes more visible when I hit an endpoint I control the response time with:

In VS2017, .net Core 2.0:

```
12/01/2017 12:03:29.725 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
12/01/2017 12:03:29.770 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
12/01/2017 12:03:29.771 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
12/01/2017 12:03:29.771 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
12/01/2017 12:03:29.771 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
12/01/2017 12:03:29.771 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
12/01/2017 12:03:29.771 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
12/01/2017 12:03:29.771 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
12/01/2017 12:03:29.771 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
12/01/2017 12:03:29.772 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
12/01/2017 12:03:34.005 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 4233 milliseconds
12/01/2017 12:03:34.005 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 4232 milliseconds
12/01/2017 12:03:34.005 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 4233 milliseconds
12/01/2017 12:03:34.005 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 4279 milliseconds
12/01/2017 12:03:34.005 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 4233 milliseconds
12/01/2017 12:03:34.005 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 4233 milliseconds
12/01/2017 12:03:34.005 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 4233 milliseconds
12/01/2017 12:03:34.005 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 4233 milliseconds
12/01/2017 12:03:34.005 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 4234 milliseconds
12/01/2017 12:03:34.005 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 4235 milliseconds
```

In VS2017, .net 4.5:

```
12/01/2017 12:03:49.972 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
12/01/2017 12:03:50.010 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
12/01/2017 12:03:50.011 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
12/01/2017 12:03:50.011 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
12/01/2017 12:03:50.011 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
12/01/2017 12:03:50.011 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
12/01/2017 12:03:50.011 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
12/01/2017 12:03:50.011 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
12/01/2017 12:03:50.011 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
12/01/2017 12:03:50.011 | DEBUG: BEGIN-ExecuteTaskAsync()
12/01/2017 12:03:54.132 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 4158 milliseconds
12/01/2017 12:03:54.132 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 4121 milliseconds
12/01/2017 12:03:58.189 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 8178 milliseconds
12/01/2017 12:03:58.191 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 8180 milliseconds
12/01/2017 12:04:02.236 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 12225 milliseconds
12/01/2017 12:04:02.239 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 12228 milliseconds
12/01/2017 12:04:06.300 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 16288 milliseconds
12/01/2017 12:04:06.302 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 16290 milliseconds
12/01/2017 12:04:10.362 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 20350 milliseconds
12/01/2017 12:04:10.364 | DEBUG: END-ExecuteTaskAsync() completed in 20352 milliseconds
```

Again, the IDE is the same, the code is identical. The applied difference being the .net version.

Comment: It's late here so I may be missing something obvious, but how can you tell from the stats that you posted that there are tasks waiting?

Comment: Maybe it's too close to my bedtime, but I copied your two output samples to text files, compared them in BeyondCompare, and the only differences I see are  in timestamps and durations, which is, of course, to be expected.  I don't see what your text output has to do with any kind of "waiting" or executing "async"

Comment: Your test method should be **async Task** not **void**

Comment: @KennethK., see my edit above for test runs which show the issue more clearly.

Comment: You need to remember that both `RestRequest` is not designed to be thread safe. Although I removed some of the shared properties, I am not sure that I can recommend using one instance to make parallel calls... This is work in progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blocking is not related to `async` mechanisms.

According to your logs in .NET 4.5, two requests are processed at a time. Your code in .NET 4.5+ hits the *2-connection-per-host* limit effective by default in `System.Net`:

> System.Net uses two connections per application per host by default

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/id-id/dotnet/framework/network-programming/best-practices-for-system-net-classes

You can change the limit as explained below. Quoting from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1f863f20-09f9-49a5-8eee-17a89b591007/asynchronous-httpwebrequest-maximum-connections-best-approach-threads-or-delegates?forum=netfxnetcom

> Having said that you can increase the number of connections per host in the following way(s):
>
> a) Increase the maximum for ALL hosts change the ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit
>
> b) Increase the maximum for a specific host retrieve the ServicePoint for a host by calling
>   ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint and then change the ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit
>
> Note that
>
> a) ALL these changes are only app domain wide and will not affect other processes connection limits.
>
> b) you are contending for the network bandwith with all other applications or threads in the same application; and if you increase the connection limit too large, you may starve other(s).
>   c) you need to experiment to find a sweet spot; for what a connection limit should be.

see also: [How can I programmatically remove the 2 connection limit in WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866350/how-can-i-programmatically-remove-the-2-connection-limit-in-webclient)

In .NET Core, this limit is not imposed by default, according to: [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit in .net core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36398474/servicepointmanager-defaultconnectionlimit-in-net-core)

Comment: Felix, thanks for  the lead. It looks like the missing glue (in .net 4.x) was to programmatically set the ConnectionLimit (during investigation, I did presume there was an artificial connection limit, but could not find any references as to where it needed to be set properly).

After setting 

System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = X

the async behavior started working as expected.