# Do I need to configure ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit if I want Azure Blob Storage to perform well?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, httpwebrequest, azure-storage

I have an asp.net app that uses Lucene.NET for search, backed by Azure blob storage. It's multi-tenanted with a separate search index per tenant. Lucene uses [AzureDirectory library](https://azuredirectory.codeplex.com/releases/view/612571) which uses [Azure Storage](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net) which uses HttpWebRequest (presumably). [Various](http://en.code-bude.net/2013/01/21/3-things-you-should-know-to-speed-up-httpwebrequest/) articles that I've been reading say if you're making concurrent outgoing web requests you should tune such parameters as [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit(v=vs.110).aspx) (to allow more than 2 simultaneous outgoing connections to the same host). Since we'll have multiple Lucene writers we'll have multiple threads at times simultaneously trying to save stuff to Azure Blob storage. So I assume the tuning advice around outgoing HttpWebRequests applies in this case. But I thought I'd check on this, since it seems like quite a fundamental limit otherwise when using something quite fundamental like Azure Storage.

Comment: This has been asked before - such as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760403/what-to-set-servicepointmanager-defaultconnectionlimit-to). This really needs to be benchmarked by you to see if it makes a difference, but often the suggestion is to set it higher than 2.

Comment: It seems like ASP.NET from IIS 7.5 (or is it from a .net version?) sets DefaultConnectionLimit to Int32.MaxValue, so this is probably not something to worry about any more when running from ASP.NET, although might be for other apps.

Comment: A useful article https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ncl/2009/08/07/new-performance-counters-for-httpwebrequest/ about performance counters that can be turned on for HttpWebRequest