# ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit returning Int32.MaxValue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

For diagnostics purposes I am logging ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit. However oddly enough it seems to be returning Int32.MaxValue (i.e 2147483647).

This seem to contradict the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit(v=vs.110).aspx) on the subject:

> The maximum number of concurrent connections allowed by a ServicePoint object. The default value is 2.

For context, I am getting this value in an ASP.Net 4 application running on 4.6.1

Comment: Here is a comment it is increased in asp.net 4.5 to `Int32.MaxValue` for web projects: [System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit == 24 --> BUG?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5649013/33499).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on @Wimmel's link it seems in ASP.Net that it is set to `Int32.MaxValue` as part of the HTTP Runtime.

We can see this by [looking inside the `System.Web` assembly at the `HttpRuntime` class](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpRuntime.cs,66640103c74bd7d4,references).

There is a method called `SetAutoConfigLimits` which sets it to `Int32.MaxValue`.
Here is the relevant excerpt:

```
private void SetAutoConfigLimits(ProcessModelSection pmConfig)
{
    int workerThreads;
    int completionPortThreads;
    ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out workerThreads, out completionPortThreads);
    if (pmConfig.DefaultMaxWorkerThreadsForAutoConfig != workerThreads || pmConfig.DefaultMaxIoThreadsForAutoConfig != completionPortThreads)
        UnsafeNativeMethods.SetClrThreadPoolLimits(pmConfig.DefaultMaxWorkerThreadsForAutoConfig, pmConfig.DefaultMaxIoThreadsForAutoConfig, true);
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = int.MaxValue;
}
```

Comment: ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = int.MaxValue; work for me. ty.