# ConnectionManagementElement.MaxConnection and ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit

Tags: c#, asp.net, servicepointmanager

I'm trying to understand what the two properties `ConnectionManagementElement.MaxConnection` and `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` are used for in managing outbound connections for ASP.net applications and if a lower value in one would limit all of the outbound connections for an application.

Based on the MSDN information for the [ServicePointManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit?view=netframework-4.7.2) the `DefaultConnectionLimit` property controls the maximum concurrent connections allowed by a `ServicePoint` object.  It says the initial value is set to 2 unless it's running on a server then it's 10, however just a simple output of the value put's it actual running value at 2147483647.  Which gets supported by the MS framework code [reference in the answer to this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36792608/servicepointmanager-defaultconnectionlimit-returning-int32-maxvalue).

Based on the [.Net Code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Configuration/ConnectionManagementElement.cs,42698797bc3ec39c) the default value for `ConnectionManagementElement.MaxConnection` is set to 1 per unique ip/domain + port when a values isn't defined in the web.config connection management section however based on a [blog from MS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tmarq/2007/07/20/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-5-iis-7-0-and-iis-6-0/) when `autoConfig = true` in the machine config the default value is 12 * #cores.  Which in my case would be 48 = 12 * 4.  There doesn't seem to be a way to get the running value for the property that the config section is setting so I'll assume for now that the value is either defined by what autoConfig determines it should be and that nothing else is overriding it.

With those details about the two properties they seem to be completely independent.  However a question posted to the [asp.net forum](https://forums.asp.net/t/1979003.aspx?Speeding%20Up%20HTTPWebRequests%20and%20the%20ServicePointManager) has an answer saying the configuration section setting is just an alternative way to now set the `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` value.

Does the web/machine config `ConnectionManagementElement.MaxConnection` get used when `autoConfig` is set to true?

If so, does `ConnectionManagementElement.MaxConnection` set the value of `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` at `Application_Start()` making synonymous to setting it as code in a defined `Application_Start()` method in the global.asax?

If not, will `ConnectionManagementElement.MaxConnection` and `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` control different limit based on what initiated the network request?